# How can i align span text left inside <td>?

Tags: html, text-alignment

This is my span tag inside  td

```
<span style="color:#556B2F;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;"> * Welcom to the Span world</span>
```

Here i want to align span text left side how can i do this,thanks for your help.

Comment: It will be aligned left. Can you provide working example in jsfiddle

Comment: Apply the style `text-align:left;` to your td(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing your question is positioning **`content set right side`** not left side because flow structure is top to bottom and left to right so default position left. But i give you answer for set left side. you can use **`table td`** align property in html and css way you can do.

```
table td{
    text-align:left;
}
```

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLjSx/)**</kbd>

Comment: If i have multiple table then this will effect on others also,right?

Comment: its depend on table width.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to do anything. Default behavior is left alignment only or put 'align=left' in your td.

Comment: when i have <td  align="left"> then its align left but i need inside td span text align left default its showing right